# EXC_BAD_ACCESS and Zombies, Yet not really sure why it keeps coming up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, instruments

I don't know what's going wrong here. The crash happens when switching back and forth between views.

Here's what instruments gives me:
[image: Crash in instruments]

Clicking into it references this code with the first action :

```
-(IBAction)pushnews; {
NewsViewController *news = [[[NewsViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
news.title =@"Page";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:news animated:YES]; }
```

I use autorelease sometimes but usually I just release it my self. Should I get rid of autorelease and add `[news retain]`

What am I doing wrong?

---

Edit based on answers:
Following EmptyStack's Advice: ViewWillDisappear Code looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
webView.delegate = nil; }
```

This seems to resolve issues (pending more testing)

In viewdidload I said: webView.delegate = self;, which may have been the issue!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but Instruments references `-[HomeViewController pushnews]`, yet you've presented `viewController`. Please post (parts of) `pushnews`.

Comment: You have *UIWebView* in *NewsViewController*?

Comment: DarkDust, I changed the name. I'm showing you the relevant portion, sorry about that. I'll edit it back and YES. I have a web view in NewsViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that, there is a *UIWebView* in *NewsViewController*, and it is causing the crash. It is possible that, a delegate method of web view is called after the web view is released. If so, try to set`webView.delegate = nil;` in *NewsViewController's* **viewWillDisappear:** method.

Comment: This bug takes a bit of effort to reproduce, but I haven't run across it yet. This also addresses why I was getting a WebView in Instruments.

Comment: This is looking good :) I'll let you guys know more once  I've deployed this across the views

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
-(IBAction)viewcontroller;
{
    NewsViewController *news = [[NewsViewController alloc]init];
    news.title =@"Page";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:news animated:YES]; 
    [news release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've done that as well, and it comes out with the same error

Comment: In fact, This was the mistake I was doing. Just because instruments said there was an error here, didn't mean there wasn't some extra stuff in the ViewController. So if you ever face the same situation, look at the view controller too!